# Python for loop matching list items at different indexes

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have data structured like so:

```
data=
[
(120,150,150,160,"word1"),
(152,150,170,160,"word2"),
(172,150,200,160,"word3"),
(202,290,240,300,"word4"),
(300,150,350,160,"word5"),
(202,200,240,210,"word6"),
(242,200,260,210,"word7")
]
```

I want to return any words in **data** where the difference between the 3rd number of the current list and the first number of the next item is less than 5 AND the difference between the 4th number of the current list item and the 4th number is less than 2 in an array. I then want to append all those arrays to a master list.

So this would be the result of the function applied to data:

```
final=
[[
(120,150,150,160,"word1"),
(152,150,170,160,"word2"),
(172,150,200,160,"word3")
],
[
(202,200,240,210,"word6"),
(242,200,260,210,"word7")
]]
```

**word4** is not included because data[2][3]-data[3][3]>2

**word5** is not included because data[3][2]-data[4][0]>2

My current attempt handles 90% of the words correctly but combines words that don't fulfill the requirements on occasion:

```
temp=[]
final=[]
for i,j in enumerate(data[:-1]):
   if(j[2]-data[i+1][0]<5) and (j[3]-data[i+1][3]<2):
       if len(temp)<1:
            temp.append(j[0:4])
       temp.append(data[i+1][0:4])
   else:
       final.append(temp)
       temp=[]
if temp:
   final.append(temp)
```

**EDIT:** Here is a real world example of the above algorithm failing:

```
data=
[
(38.0, 296.7943420410156, 90.86400604248047, 310.7943420410156, 'Contract'),(94.7560043334961, 296.7943420410156, 154.6480102, 310.7943420, 'Summary'), 
(250.64453125, 317.38818359375, 266.743530, 325.88818359375, 'This')
]
```

Expected output:

```
final=
[[
(38.0, 296.7943420410156, 90.86400604248047, 310.7943420410156, 'Contract'),(94.7560043334961, 296.7943420410156, 154.6480102, 310.7943420, 'Summary')
]]
```

Actual output:

```
final=
[[
(38.0, 296.7943420410156, 90.86400604248047, 310.7943420410156, 'Contract'),(94.7560043334961, 296.7943420410156, 154.6480102, 310.7943420, 'Summary'),
(250.64453125, 317.38818359375, 266.743530, 325.88818359375, 'This')
]]
```

Comment: I think you left out something in the condition related to the 4th number. Which index are you comparing it with? Is it also being compared with the next item?

Comment: `j[i]` should be `j[3]`

Comment: Thanks that was actually a typo on my end.

Comment: You need to do `if temp: final.append(temp)` at the end of the loop to get the last group.

Comment: I will add that to the example code as it does help but doesn't address the primary question. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't see anythinhg that will add items that shouldn't be added. Can you provide sample input and the incorrect results?

Comment: Instead of `for i,j in enumerate(data[:-1]):` I suggest `for (A,B,C,D,S), (a,b,c,d,s) in zip(data, data[1:]):` so that the condition doesn't have a ton of indices and becomes easier to read: `if abs(C-c) < 5 and abs(D-d) < 2:`

Comment: Added a sample of something that failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the numbers and adding `abs` since the diff might be negative. I also prettified your code a bit:

```py
data = [
    (38.0, 296.7943420410156, 90.86400604248047, 310.7943420410156, 'Contract'),
    (94.7560043334961, 296.7943420410156, 154.6480102, 310.7943420, 'Summary'),
    (250.64453125, 317.38818359375, 266.743530, 325.88818359375, 'This')
]

temp = []
final = []
for index, item in enumerate(data[:-1]):
    if abs(item[2] - data[index + 1][0]) < 5 and abs(item[3] - data[index + 1][3]) < 2:
        if len(temp) < 1:
            temp.append(item[0:4])
        temp.append(data[index + 1][0:4])
    else:
        final.append(temp)
        temp = []
if temp:
    final.append(temp)

print(final)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider the negative difference.